# jQuery UI sortable('toArray') not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am relative jQuery noob and have been unable to find an answer to this elsewhere. I have a table of tasks that can be sorted to rank their priority. When they change position the data variable will be used in an ajax call to rebuild the table based on the new sort order.

I have the following example mark up:

```
<table id="sortable"><tbody id="tasks_96" class="ui-sortable">
    <tr class="blue_1 task_style ui-sortable-handle" id="204">
         <td>Task 204</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="blue_2 task_style ui-sortable-handle" id="203">
         <td>Task 203</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And I have the following listener:

```
$("#sortable tbody").sortable(sortOptions);
```

And options:

```
var sortOptions = {
                update: function(event, ui){

                  // retrieve order of ids, filter out empty values
                  var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').filter(Boolean);

                  // retrieve staffid (slice out the 'tasks_' part from the id)
                  var staffid = event.target.id.slice(6);
                  var data    = { 'staffid' : staffid, 'order' : order };

                  console.log(data);

                  // make ajax call with data
                  ....
                }
```

Expected console output would be "Object {staffid: "96", order: Array[2]}" but I am getting "Object {staffid: "96", order: Array[0]}".

Note: without the sortable('toArray') call, the sort works fine...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does method call rebuildTaskTable(staffid); do? Have you tried to comment that line for testing purposes

Comment: hi there, I should have explained this in the question! I am using the sort functionality to rebuild a table of tasks to show their priority based on their position in the table. I did note 'this' on the first sort returns the original html and not the new sort...

Comment: I commented that out and the sort works again....

Comment: with the ajax call commented out the order variable continues to be empty...I will look into the setting this properly on the first call...

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code posted. Can you include what happens when you `rebuildTaskTable()` or even better [make a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @blgt thanks for your comment, Ive tightened up the question a little...the rebuildTaskTable function simply rebuilds the markup and resets the listeners so I dont think its part of the problem...